# Android Studio Showing Logcat but not my Log calls

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, logcat

Logcat is displaying all logs other than the ones I explicitly call for.
Here is a small snippet of where the log call is nested within a Dropdown Menu

```kotlin
TextField(
    value = songVar,
    onValueChange = {
        songVarChanged(it)
        // more code here to assigning new value to selectedOptions.value
        Log.d("value", selectedOptions.value.toString())
    },
    label = { Text("name") },
```

When my dropdown box changes based on a value I select, I get no output named **value** or any string that should be in the list.

I checked back from a previous project where something similar worked within a checkbox. Nothing changed when I used my Samsung Galaxy S21 Ultra or if I used a Pixel 3a in the emulator. Same issue.